# Data not present in newly added column in webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have added a new field in universe. Field is present in available object and showing data on data preview but when I drag and drop the field in report it's not showing any data.

If I add it on a blank report it's showing data. What could be possible wrong here? Any suggestion?

I have already tried removing filters.

Comment: maybe the extra data you put in is not compatible with the already existing data in your report? For example if you already have the column 'calendar date' and you only have dates for example of the month September, if you add your new column and it only has compatible data for the previous year you will not get any data in your new column.

Comment: Data is current data getting updated weekly basis. Field was already present in hana view we Just add it in webi

Comment: yes, but maybe there is a field in your webi which if the new data is added returns null values for your new data. Try to add the new data and then 1 by 1 delete the other columns from your report and check when you get data in your new column, that will be the column which returns the null values for your new data

Comment: Hi mrdeadsven this worked now i know which column is restricting new data.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!